# GCP AppEngine gives permission denied when deploying a spring boot application using content api for shopping

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have created a Google Merchant account which creates a project in Google Cloud Console. I deployed an application in google AppEngine using the service account created by the Merchant account to use the content api for shopping by specifying it in the `app.yaml` file. Although the same service account credentials are used in my local development setup is fine. I get the following error.

```
{
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]    "code" : 403,
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]    "errors" : [ {
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]      "domain" : "global",
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]      "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]      "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]    } ],
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]    "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED",
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]    "details" : [ {
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]      "@type" : "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]      "reason" : "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]      "domain" : "googleapis.com",
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]      "metadata" : {
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]        "service" : "shoppingcontent.googleapis.com",
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]        "method" : "ads.shopping.contentapi.proto.frontend.v2p1.ContentAccounts.Authinfo"
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]      }
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]    } ]
2022-05-01 17:42:07 default[20220501t230020]  }
```

But the service account already has permissions defined to access the content api(since same service account credentials are used locally). I have given permission to access the cloud sql instance for the sam service account and it is working in both locally and in the cloud. I don't know what the issue is any help is appreciated??

Comment: have you enabled stackdriver debugging  API or App engine admin Api?

Comment: i ve enabled app engine admin api @DivyaniYadav

Comment: can you try enabling stackdriver debugging api?